# PHP - possible to predefine a variable (not property of class) for use within a method?

Tags: php, constructor, scope

**Simple example**

I would like to know if there is any possible way that `$data` could already exist without being set in that method, and if so how to set it.

```
public function index(){

   if(isset($data)){
       //how is this possible?

   } else if(isset($this->data){
       // set in parent::__construct
       // ok i'm going to have to set $data in every method in every controller
       $data = $this->data;
   }
}
```

**additional info**

This is my specific problem,

I am using a framework with a controller class which is extended for every controller.

```
class ControllerBlog extends Controller {}
```

Every method in every controller perform a few almost identical tasks. Some of these tasks return data within the scope of the method called.

```
//e.g
public function index(){
    $this->loadthis('blog');
     $this->loadthat('blog');

    $data = $this->get_this('blog');

     ... 
     ...
    $data['title'] = 'blog title';

     use_data($data);
}
```

I would like to move these tasks to  Controller class function __construct to limit the amount of code repeated.

```
<?php
    class Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            //load this and that and return data;
            $data = $this->load_and_return_all(get_class($this));

            //class level
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }
```

is there a way to get the $data variable for use within the scope of the method without the need of adding any additional code to every method of every controller?

```
class ControllerBlog extends Controller {

   public function index(){ 

      //adding this to every method seems silly
      $data = $this->data;
      // i would like $data to be set in the construct;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd say no, there's no way to do that. You'll always need additional code

Comment: You do not need to assign this->data to a var, you could use $this->data directly? at least you'll skip the assignation? Maybe I did get your question wrong...

Comment: if i skip assigning $data i would have to rename all instances of $data to $this->data. the annoying thing is the framework has just switched from using $this->data

Comment: No, there is no way to do it. Yes, just rename everything to `$this->data`. A find-and-replace in your text editor can do this pretty quickly.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem but the first condition in your *simple example* reminds of good old [static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)

Comment: I agree with TarranJones and deceze - the problem with using a third party framework is you are not the architect. If you want to make it easier on yourself, fork their copy of the framework and make the changes you need in order to use `$this->data`.